# Oozie done-flag EL functions

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

I am trying to use the built in or EL functions provided by oozie in  tag of oozie-coordinator xml, but seems like its not supported? Does anyone know of any other way to declare this?

Our done-flags have dates in them.

```xml
<done-flag>${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}.done</done-flag>
OR
<done-flag>${coord:formatTime(coord:actualTime(), 'yyyyMMdd')}</done-flag>
```

I get the following error when launching the oozie coordinator workflow.

```
Error: E1004 : E1004: Expression language evaluation error, 
Unable to evaluate :${coord:formatTime(coord:actualTime(), 'yyyyMMdd')}:
```

Does anyone know of a way to achieve dynamic done-flag names?

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure about what you want to do.

My understanding is that the Coordinator waits for a file named as "done-flag" before running a Workflow. **Then** the "coord:actualTime()" function can be used to know at what time the Workflow was actually started.

*=> the [documentation](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a6.7.4._coord:actualTime_EL_Function) should stress that the phrase "coordinator action" actually means "workflow" in most cases...*

If you want to check the clock time while the Coordinator is still waiting, the keywords [YEAR - MONTH - DAY - HOUR - MINUTE](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.1.0/CoordinatorFunctionalSpec.html#a5.1._Synchronous_Datasets) are your only hope.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working using the following way, by using the YEAR, MONTH, DAY variables in the uri-template and emptying out the .

```
  <uri-template>
    /donemarkers/dependency-job/${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}.done
  </uri-template>
  <!--<done-flag>${YEAR}${MONTH}${DAY}.done</done-flag>-->
  <done-flag></done-flag>
```

I came to know from the logs that oozie first checks if there is a directory with the name specified by uri-template, if not then it checks if there is a file specified by the uri-template.

```
2015-07-28 19:40:46,225  INFO CoordActionInputCheckXCommand:539 - USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0131647-140520191754742-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[0131647-140520191754742-oozie-oozi-C@2] [0131647-140520191754742-oozie-oozi-C@2]::ActionInputCheck:: In checkResolvedUris...
2015-07-28 19:40:46,225  INFO CoordActionInputCheckXCommand:539 - USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0131647-140520191754742-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[0131647-140520191754742-oozie-oozi-C@2] [0131647-140520191754742-oozie-oozi-C@2]::ActionInputCheck:: In checkListOfPaths: /donemarkers/dependency-job/20150725.done is Missing.
2015-07-28 19:40:46,241  INFO CoordActionInputCheckXCommand:539 - USER[-] GROUP[-] TOKEN[-] APP[-] JOB[0131647-140520191754742-oozie-oozi-C] ACTION[0131647-140520191754742-oozie-oozi-C@2] [0131647-140520191754742-oozie-oozi-C@2]::ActionInputCheck:: File:/donemarkers/dependency-job/20150725.done, Exists? :true
```